# How to separate username and email on ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I'm so newbie in here as I try to learn this new stuff. But, I have a problem. On asp.net core identity, there's no AccountController (as many blog say it should be modified there), so how can I modify this? I'm so confused with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Identity has a default UI that's included programmatically, via `AddDefaultIdentity` (which calls `AddDefaultUI` under the hood). You can use the Identity scaffold to add just the parts you want to modify, which works like an overload: anything not explicitly included in your project falls back to the default UI version.

Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, go to "Add" and then "New Scaffolded Item..." On the left of the resulting window, there's a tab for "Identity", which has just one scaffold to choose from, "Identity". Click the "Add" button. This will get you yet another window, where you can now choose which items you want to scaffold into your project.

Be advised that Identity's default UI makes use of Razor Pages, now, so you still won't get an `AccountController` and such. However, you can simply include pages like `Account\Register` and `Account\Login`, which should be the two places you would need to make this change. Feel free to add and modify anything else you like as well.

Comment: Thanks! So, I can just separate username and email as individual field on there? Like, in the registration page, there's a username (which is they're unique name, like presscotNathan45), email, and password. So, when the user in the account dashboard, the username is not they're email anymore, and if you have a tutorial how can I make username can make change it would be more great. Thank you!